# Codeigniter form in modal bootstrap failed passing multiple chekbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a form in modal bootstrap. In codeigniter form, i left the form_open is blank, because I want the page is still not move to another page. The code is like this :

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    $properties = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'myform', 'name' => 'myform');
    echo form_open("", $properties);
    ?>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Jenis Request :</label>
            <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" /> Login </label>
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer" value="Printer"/> Printer </label>
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor" value="Monitor"/> Monitor</label>
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer"/> Computer</label>
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network" value="Network"/> Network</label>
                <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Other" value="Lain-lain" /> Other</label> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
            <label class="control-label" for="Keluhan" >Description: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea class="cleditor" name="keluhan" id="keluhan" rows="3" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Kirim</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn" id="reset">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

See, I use jquery to insert a new data on my database like this :

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myform', function() {
        $('#myform').block({
            message: '<h2>Sedang mencari</h2>',
            css: {border: '3px solid #a00'}
        });

        var request = $("input[name='request[]']:checked");
        var keluhan = $("#keluhan").val();



        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'direksi/control_direksi/mdRequest' ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {request: request,
                keluhan: keluhan},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Insert Success");
                $("myModal").hide();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

And this is the php action

```
public function mdRequest() {

    var_dump($_POST);

}
```

My page just refreshed without affected. How to check if the POST was success ?
And how to passed multiple checkbox using jquery, am I wrong like on my code above ? Any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the values by using array variable. Store checked element inside array variable like so :

```
var request = $("input[name='request[]']:checked").map(function(i,e) {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

To check POST request success or not, you can check via network tab for chrome browser, and see the ajax request success or not. Second, display output by using `console.log()`. This will print out the output of `var_dump`. :

```
 success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("myModal").hide();
 }
```

In server side, you can use this function as well :

```
public function mdRequest() {
  print_r($this->input->post());
  // or print_r($this->input->post('request'));
}
```